# Python find the max date in a list which are no later than a given date

Tags: python, date

I want to compare a date string to a list of date strings, and find out the max date in the list which are no later than the date given.

```
date='2015-04-16'

dates=[str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-05-01'
    ,str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-09-01'
    ,str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-11-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-05-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-09-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-11-01']
```

The right output should be the third element in dates, which is '2014-11-01'.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've used a lexicographically-ordered date format, you can compare the strings directly. Finding the maximum of a group of items is the job of `max()`. Choosing what items go in the group can be done by a generator expression.

```
date='2015-04-16'

dates=[str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-05-01'
    ,str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-09-01'
    ,str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-11-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-05-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-09-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-11-01']

print max(x for x in dates if x < date)
```

References:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max
- https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

If your list is sorted (as in your example), you can do this very efficiently using Python's [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module:

```
import bisect

date='2015-04-16'

dates=[str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-05-01'
    ,str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-09-01'
    ,str(int(date[:4])-1)+'-11-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-05-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-09-01'
    ,date[:4]+'-11-01']

i = bisect.bisect(dates, date)
# Subtract one from the insertion point to find the previous date.
print dates[i - 1]
```